# Parse Tree Formatter Tools?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, parsing, tools

I am looking for tools that can ***format parse trees***.  I want to be able to collapse and expand them.  I understand that collapsing them is rather simple with regex or even simple search and replace, but I am doing some testing which requires me to work with a large amount of trees for testing.

When I say expand, I mean pretty print them in a way that represents the tree

For example, the following parse tree:

```
(S (VP (DT He) (VBP ran)))
```

Expands out to:

```
(S
    (VP
        (DT He) 
        (VBP ran)
    )
)
```

Again, I understand collapsing them back is rather simple, but I have a lot of trees to test.. AND these trees can be quite large.  I tried googling variations on "parse syntax tree tools formatter" and wasn't finding anything.  This would be something similar to a programming language beautifier.

**Any links for online syntax tools would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: You could just look for a Lisp or Scheme pretty printer, which would do the job, though perhaps not exactly with the same output like you specify here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a script I quickly assembled from pieces of code I had lying around:

https://trinket.io/python3/a33a025467?toggleCode=true&showInstructions=true

Beware that this script parses your tree very naively; it just processes the input symbol by symbol and does some formatting when it encounters opening or closing brackets; it will not warn you if you have any syntax errors in your tree structure.

I included the option to set a mode (plain or fancy), indentation depth and permitted opening/closing brackets - to change the settings, click the pen button, change the code and hit the play button to re-run the script; the usage of the settings is hopefully self-explanatory enough even if you don't know Python. This could of course be made more user-friendly if one had time.

Example (plain mode, indentation depth 4):

```
Place your flat tree here:

(S (VP (DT He) (VBP ran)))

Here is your inflated tree:

(S 
    (VP 
        (DT He)
        (VBP ran)
    )
)
```

Example (fancy mode, indentation depth 3):

```
Place your flat tree here:

(S (VP (DT He) (VBP ran)))

Here is your inflated tree:

|-- S 
|   |-- VP 
|   |   |-- DT He
|   |   |-- VBP ran
```

Probably if someone messes up the script in the edit mode with this online tool, it will be lost for good, so here is the source code for restoration:

```
"""
This is a simple script for formatting tree structures.
Author: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/13238/lemontree

You can customize
- whether to use plain and fancy printout (default: plain),
- the depth of indentation (default: 4),
- the permitted opening and closing brackets (default: "[", "("),
by editing the settings in the source code.

Exmple input:
[S [NP [PRN This]] [VP [V is] [NP [D a] [N tree]]]]

"""

# print the documentation
print(__doc__)

# settings -- make your changes here
mode = "plain"        # set the printout mode (one out of "plain" or "fancy")
ind_depth = 4         # set the amount of spaces by which you want each nesting level to be indented
opening = ["(", "["]  # set the symbol sequences which signal the start of a subtree
closing = [")", "]"]  # set the symbol sequences which signal the end   of a subtree

# ask for tree input
tree_in = input("Place your flat tree here:\n")

# generate formatted tree
tree_out = ""
ind_level = -1
for char in tree_in:  # parse each character

    # opening bracket found - new nesting level; increase ind. level, add newline and indentation
    if char in opening:
        ind_level += 1
        if mode == "plain":
            tree_out += "\n" + \
                        (ind_level * ind_depth) * " "
        elif mode == "fancy":
            tree_out += "\n" + \
                        (ind_level * ("|" + ind_depth * " ") if ind_level > 0 else "") + \
                        "|" + (ind_depth-1) * "-" + " "

    # append current symbol
    if mode == "plain":
        tree_out += char
    elif mode == "fancy":
        if char not in opening and char not in closing:
            tree_out += char

    # closing bracket found - end of nesting level; decrease ind. level and add newline
    if char in closing:
        ind_level -= 1
        if mode == "plain":
            tree_out += "\n" + \
                        (ind_level * ind_depth) * " "
        elif mode == "fancy":
            tree_out += "\n" + \
                        (ind_level * ind_depth + 1) * " " + \
                        "\n"

tree_out = "\n".join([line for line in tree_out.splitlines() if line.split()])  # remove blank lines

# output formatted tree
print("\nHere is your inflated tree:\n")
print(tree_out)
```

If anyone has recommendations on possibly better online Python interpreters which permit running code with user input, I'm happy to learn about them.

Comment: Ah, WOW!!! Why thank you lemontree!  Is there a way I can give you more points?

Comment: If you want, you can sacrifice some of your own reputation to [award a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).